# How to change childAspectRatio dynamically in Grid View

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using `GridView` & i have defined `childAspectRatio` for defining item size. i want different item size for different items, below is my Grid View Code -

```
GridView.count(
                crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                 childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),//Need to change this dynamically
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Flutter has explained about listview here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list. But i am looking same thing in GridView. & dont want to rely on any third party pub

Comment: https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: @AmitPrajapati dont want to use third party pub.

Comment: True, but you can find logic from it.

Comment: u could use variable for each item and change its value via setState

Comment: @Lukas Can you add it as answer ?